# Deploy asp.net mvc beta to iis 6 causing 404's

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6, http-status-code-404

I'm struggling to get around the 404 errors from asp.net mvc beta when deploying on IIS 6. I had this working in one of the previews by mapping .mvc in IIS but this no longer works. I've read [Omar's post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/omar/archive/2008/06/30/deploy-asp-net-mvc-on-iis-6-solve-404-compression-and-performance-problems.aspx) and several others on the web and tried their solutions but no luck so far.

The home page opens without a problem on IIS 6 but others 404 and the site runs well on IIS 7.

Has anybody deployed asp.net mvc beta to IIS 6 with success? If so, what adjustments did you need to make to the code and/or IIS settings to get it to work?

Comment: For S&G's... check your wildcard mapping.  Is that little checkbox "Check that File Exists" checked?  I hate that little bastard.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem from [Steve Sanderson's blog](http://blog.codeville.net/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/) (Thanks Steve):

Use a wildcard mapping for `aspnet_isapi.dll`. This tells IIS 6 to process all requests using ASP.NET, so routing is always invoked, and there’s no problem. It’s dead easy to set up:

- open IIS manager (run -> inetmgr -> OK)
- right-click your app, go to Properties
- then Home Directory tab, then click Configuration.
- Under Wildcard application maps, click Insert (not Add, which is
  confusingly just above)
- then enter
  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll for
  “Executable”, and uncheck Verify that file exists.

Comment: Perfect! This solved my problem after an hour and a half of banging my head against a wall.

Comment: Great fix. Saved me A LOT of time. Thanks

Comment: What a pain that was! In the immortal words of Napoleon Dynamite: "Flippin' Sweet!"

Answer (score 5):

I can't seem to write comments yet. So I'll write a new answer.

There are a few similar questions going around on stackoverflow. 
I'm using MVC 3. I know the question was MVC 2 related. But since this is the first stackoverflow post I bumped in to, I think it's worth mentioning that:

- when you use MVC 3, you need to add a new extension mapping with the executable of the .NET 4 framework (C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll)

<edit>I just found out that I even don't need to set up the extension mapping.  </edit>

- It still didn't work for me then :) I still had to 'Allow' ASP.NET v4.0.30319 in the Web Service Extensions section in IIS:

  - open IIS
  - click on the server node
  - open the Web Service Extensions section
  - select the ASP.NET v4.0....
  - right click --> Allow
    Good to go!

Comment: Thank you, that Web Service Extensions helped me out. Why would it default to Prohibited on a fresh install??

Answer (score 1):

Url rewriting can help you to solve the problem. I've implemented solution allowing to deploy MVC application at any IIS version even when virtual hosting is used.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/iis-aspnet-url-rewriting.aspx