# Deploy ASP.NET MVC on IIS 5.1 (Windows XP)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, iis-5

OK, deploying ASP.NET MVC seems to be painful. I want to deploy my ASP.NET MVC application on Windows XP (IIS 5.1), but can't seem to find how to do it. When I type the application name into the web browser address bar I get a "website not available" message.

There are workarounds for [IIS 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239981/deploy-aspnet-mvc-beta-to-iis-6-causing-404s), but what about IIS 5.1?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here's what I found out and what worked for *me*:
[Deploy ASP.NET MVC App on Windows XP (IIS 5.1)](http://itscommonsensestupid.blogspot.com/2008/11/deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-on-windows-xp-iis.html)

**Edit:**

For the latest release of ASP.NET MVC, replace .mvc with a wildcard .* Extension textbox in the Add/Edit Application Extension mapping.

Comment: Hi, when I add extension `.*`, cgi calls dont work. Can you suggest any solution to run MVC as well as CGI on IIS 5.1?

Comment: @BabyDuck, maybe you should ask a new question

Answer (score 20):

You need to add a wildcard mapping in IIS 5. In IIS 6 you have a specific section to add wildcard mappings. In IIS 5 you map the extension .* and you select your asp.net ISAPI dll. If the "Ok" button is not clickable, click in the textbox of the dll path and it should then be clickable (don't ask, this happens to me all the time).

Comment: and what if its still grayed out when I click on the textbox ??

Comment: It is a bug on IIS 5.1.
Workaround: After browsing for the asp.net ISAPI dll, click in the file text box to expand the full path, this will activate the OK button.

Comment: I'll also had to disable the option (checkbox) "Check that the file exists".  This was found while fixing mvc & cassette issues on IIS 5.1 winxp.

Answer (score 6):

To host ASP .NET MVC applications in Windows XP, use [IIS Developer Express](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1038).

After IIS Express is installed, open a command prompt at the install location and execute the following (substituting where necessary):

> iisexpress.exe
>   /path:[path_to_mvc_project]
>   /port:[port] /systray:true /clr:v2.0

Answer (score 1):

The *same* process (using Ionic rewriter) which works for 6.0 works for us on 5.x. What do you see in the Windows App Event log? And the IIS server log? Have you tried a rewriter?