# Getting 404 error with ASP.NET MVC starter project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I just created a ASP.NET MVC project and was able to build and browse it using the Visual Studio Development Server.

When I tried to change from Visual Studio Development Server to my local IIS (IIS 5.1) under the project properties Web -> Server.  I am able to browse to the default page, but when I browse to any other page I get a 404 error.

The root of my site and virtual directory is http://localhost/MyMvcApplication

Is there a different configuration when using IIS?

Comment: Have you setup wildcard mapping in IIS on your local machine?

Comment: @David Liddle - I do not think so.  I am running IIS 5.1 on a Windows XP Pro machine

Comment: pls refer this article for the solution : [http://tugberkugurlu.com/archive/running-asp-net-mvc-under-iis-6-0-and-iis-7-0-classic-mode---solution-to-routing-problem](http://tugberkugurlu.com/47)

Comment: Ironically the article link is giving a 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Deploy ASP.NET MVC on IIS 5.1 (Windows XP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301359/deploy-asp-net-mvc-on-iis-5-1-windows-xp)

Answer (score 3):

You have to setup wildcard mapping to the aspnet_isapi.dll (IIS site configuration). This means that every request to the server is parsed by the .NET DLL so that URL's can be rewritten (MVC heavily relies on URL rewriting).