# Deploying an ASP .NET MVC 3 web application under IIS 5.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, deployment

I have developped a web application by using the ASP .NET MVC 3 framework.
Therefore I have got a Visual Studio 2010 project to develop my web application.
I want to deploy my web application under IIS 5.1 on a remote machine.

I know I have to create a virtual directory under the IIS default web site node.
The virtual directory will be linked to a directory in the File Management System of the remote machine.
The FMS directory will contain files of my web application.

**Question** : What files and folders of my VS2010 project must be present in the FMS directory ?

I intend to create a folder named bin in the FMS directory.
The bin folder will contain DLLs used by my web application and not present in the GAC of the remote machine.

**Question** : Will I have to modify the Web.config file ?

The folder corresponding to my VS2010 project contains a folder named bin as well.
The bin folder contains a DLL with the same name of my application.

**Question** : What is this DLL used for ?

Comment: Are you sure it's IIS 5.1?  That's Windows 2000 isn't it?

Comment: Yes I am sure IIS 5.1 runs on the remote machine. The OS is Windows XP on the remote machine.

Comment: Is this to be a production environment? Or are you just needing to test out what the site will do under IIS in general?

Comment: This will be the production environment. My web application has to be used by developpers in my company. The remote machine is in my company. Therefore I have got a direct access to the remote machine.

Comment: Keep in mind there is a 10 connection limit on IIS on Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered on Stackoverflow before. [Deploy ASP.NET MVC on IIS 5.1 (Windows XP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301359/deploy-asp-net-mvc-on-iis-5-1-windows-xp). (Note that the accepted answer is now linking to a page that will throw a warning of malware existing on the site.)

As a suggestion, I would see if you could get a machine which is running IIS7 or better rather than dealing with the headache of having to configure routes and which executables to setup on IIS itself. With IIS7 all you really have to do to make it work is to bin deploy the mvc specific .dll's (this is a setting inside visual studio, found under the properties of the website, under package/publish web) when you deploy the site.

*As a side note, you should be able to get IIS7 on Vista, and 7.5 on Windows 7.*

Good luck, and hope this information helps getting your application up and going.

Comment: I took a look on the website mentionned in the correct answer but I did not find any answer to my questions. IIS 7 is probably a better web server in my position but I can not change the OS on the remote machine and I can not install another version of IIS.